# web server can be accessed by network computer but not remote, checked port fwding

Tags: webserver, windows-firewall, dynamic-ip

I am running out of things I know to check for this problem: I am running a web server on port 3000, before I go on any further, I'd like to mention that I have been able to access the server from remote computers, i.e., from another internet connection, I got my port forwarding for 3000 for this computer's ip, got the proper external ip, but since yesterday, I don't know what happened, it stopped working.

Now I have another computer that I host another server on 9999, it works fine. So that tells me that the port forwarding on the router IS working properly. Then I went to see if this other computer can see the web server on this problematic computer, and yes, it can. So I concluded that it is not a firewall issue on this problematic computer since it would have prevented networked computer to access the webserver.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I checked the hosts file in system32/drivers/etc, all lines are commented out. I haven't touched this anyway, but I thought I should mention it.

Is there something else that you can think of that I can try checking?

Win7 64bit
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So right now all you know is that you can't view the web page in a browser?

I would run a packet capture tool (like wireshark) to see if any connection requests are reaching the server computer.  If port forwarding isn't setting the right destination port this would help find it, also if packets are being forwarded and the web server software is choosing to ignore them due to a configuration issue, packet capture would also help

Comment: the webserver(mongrel) works locally and I can access it from another computer on the same network. And I think the port-forwarding is working for all the other computers on the network except this one since yesterday. Naturally, I make sure the port forwarding's pointing IP matches the one on this computer. But to no avail....

Comment: Okay, I restarted the router, and it now works...I don't know what happened...